# XPages DojoDataGrid does not work with bootstrap theme

Tags: xpages, bootstrapping

İ need to use dojoDataGrid with bootstrap theme. but it does not work with bootstrap. is there any solution for this?

if i use OneUI2 or below DojoDataGrid displays all data with custom Rest Service

if i try to use OneUI 2.1 and above especcially any version of Bootstrap theme for the application DojoDataGrid does not display data...

I have to use Custom Rest Service ([similar to this](http://xcellerant.net/2014/01/09/dojo-data-grid-33-reading-custom-rest-service/))
to get data into DojoDataGrid from different databases and different views

[image: Screenshot with OneUI 2]
[image: Screenshow with bootstrap Theme]

Comment: Please clarify what "it does not work" means.

Comment: I tried to clarify my problem. i tried to disableTheme=true for the page or dojoDataGrid. It did not work either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems to be a problem with themes newer than OneUI 2.0. You can get around it though if you set a height on the djxDataGrid control. I just tested this on 9.0.1 FP5 + ExtLib 15, so results may vary with older versions.

```
<xe:djxDataGrid id="djxDataGrid1" store="dataStore" style="height: 500px;">
```

**EDIT**: I think I prefer Knut's suggestion below to use autoHeight, as that is actually a dojo property, and specifying the number of rows to display in the grid is more intuitive.

```
<xe:djxDataGrid id="djxDataGrid1" store="dataStore" autoHeight="20">
```

Comment: Instead of style you can use `autoHeight="20"` with the number of rows too.